# jQuery formatting data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get my code to show the current bitcoin price, and I'm hitting a bit of a wall. It shows nothing. Can anyone please help me?https://blockchain.info/da/ticker

Here is the data I'm using. It's in a file on my server for now.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    document.write(data[0].USD[0].last);
  });
});
```

Comment: have you tried `console.log(data)` what does it show?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam https://imgur.com/4yqFlq9

Comment: added an answer please confirm

Comment: Did you try to access as object data.USD.symbol ?

Comment: I posted a pick with the data it shows in my console. It weirdly only shows the usd data in there. @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: @ChristianFrandsen there is a difference in the data that you have shared in the OP and the one that you have posted in your comments..

Comment: thats what you intended to in your code `document.write(data[0].USD[0].last);` , are you trying to print all the currencies ?

Answer (score -1):

There is a difference in the data that you have shared in the link in your question, And the image of data that you have posted in the comments. So I will be providing solution for both.

- Syntax if you have data as in link
  [image]

  `data.USD.last`

And

- Syntax if your data is as per this image. 
  [image]

  `data[0].USD.last`

Comment: aaj mode bindaas hai, ja down vote wapis liya ayashy ker gee le apni zindagy **(⌐■_■)**